# Matching strings and extracting parts

Tags: python, regex

I've an issue here. I have a string and I want to extract parts of it using regex. Here is the string

**{{name}} I love me some work {{hero}}**

I want to extract

`[{{name}}, {{hero}}]`

also in a case where the string exist as

**{{name} I love me some work {{hero, come in {here, this is right}**

I still want to get

`[{{name}, {{name, {here, right}]`

I hope this makes sense. I am working with Python.

Comment: The second string has unbalanced parenthesis.Are you sure of it?

Comment: Hey @vks, yes I am sure about it. The idea is to extract that too. I want to run validation on the results to make sure that no one sends in string with unbalance parenthesis.

Comment: Please define how do you want to get from **{{name} I love me some work {{hero, come in {here, this is right}** to `[{{name}, {{name, {here, right}]`

Comment: Hi @pacholik, someone already solved it for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `['{{name}}', '{{hero}}', '{{hero, come in {here, this is right}']` use @Avinash's regex.

If you want `['{{name}}', '{{hero}}', '{{hero', {here', 'right}']` use the following:

```
re.findall(r'{+\w+}*|{*\w+}+', s)
```

[RegEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iO5aL8/1)

Comment: Thanks @karthik, your solution did solve my problem. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
import re
s = '{{name} I love me some work {{hero, come in {here, this is right}'
print re.findall(r'\{.*?\}', s)
```

Comment: Hi @siwel, thanks for your answer, I did try it but it didn't capture **{{name}} I love me some work {{hero}}, {{hero, come in {here, this is right}, how about we go dancing}}** well. It missed some part.